# Reorder the context menu and add dividers in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to rearrange the order of the context menu items and possibly add dividers between them for grouping?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customize-viewer-context-menu to make a custom context menu.

For dividers I found functionality in the source code:

```
menu.push({divider: true})
```

Snippet of the source code for show() in contextMenu:

```
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; ++i) {
var defn = menu[i],
title = defn.title,
target = defn.target,
icon = defn.icon,
shortcut = defn.shortcut,
divider = defn.divider;

var hasChildren = Array.isArray(target);

if (hasChildren && !menu.isChild) {
  addExpandDiv = true; // Keep track of any item that is expandable
} else {
  // As described in the design, limit the the number of menu levels to two.
  // We will flatten the target array
  hasChildren = false;
}

if (divider) {
  menuItem = this.createDivider();
  menuDiv.appendChild(menuItem);
} else {
```